# Why does firewalld enabled after a reboot and after a restart have a different behavior?

Tags: centos, rhel, iptables, firewalld, nftables

I'm on Centos 8 Stream, a rolling release version using `4.18.0-301.1.el8.x86_64` and I find weird and non consistent behavior.

Depending on how firewalld is started, it has a different behavior.

- When firewalld is booted at the boot, it adds LIBVIRT_* chains.
- When firewalld is restarted with systemctl, all these chains disappear.
- Why?

```bsh
# nftables after the reboot
$ nft list tables
table ip filter
table ip nat
table ip mangle
table ip6 filter
table ip6 nat
table ip6 mangle

# nftables after the systemctl restart
$ nft list tables
table ip filter
table ip nat
table ip mangle
table ip6 filter
table ip6 nat
table ip6 mangle
table bridge filter
table ip security
table ip raw
table ip6 security
table ip6 raw
table bridge nat
table inet firewalld
table ip firewalld
table ip6 firewalld
```

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:68

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    

$ sudo systemctl restart firewalld

$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

That is very perturbing and is very hard to debug. Especially after I start the openvpn-as service, it adds iptables chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not precisely `firewalld` that's adding those chains. As the names of the chains suggest, it's `libvirt` adding them on top of your `firewalld` configuration.

CentOS 8 Stream's factory default configuration includes some preparations for running virtual machines (or for nested virtualization, if the CentOS 8 system itself is a VM). If you don't need to run VMs on your CentOS, you might want to disable those.

I don't have a CentOS 8 Stream test system at hand right now, but I think this should do it:

```
virsh net-destroy default              # unconfigure what libvirtd has done for now
systemctl stop libvirtd.service        # stop the service
systemctl disable libvirtd.service     # persistently disable it
```

If you want to keep `libvirtd` running for some purpose, but want to disable its default network settings, this might do it (but I'm less sure if this will clear the iptables additions or not):

```
virsh net-destroy default           # unconfigure what libvirtd has done for now
virsh net-undefine default          # persistently remove libvirtd network config
```

Or maybe just: (this should be undoable without reinstalling libvirtd or otherwise restoring the default configuration)

```
virsh net-destroy default               # unconfigure what libvirtd has done for now
virsh net-autostart default --disable   # tell libvirt to not autostart default config
```

To undo the 3rd version, just use `virsh net-autostart default` without the `--disable` option, and restart the `libvirtd` service or reboot.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I thought VIRTLIB was used by firewalld! Nevertheless that doesn't tell me why they disappear when I restart firewalld...

Comment: Restarting Firewalld erases all the other services' rules (iptables and nftables)

Comment: libvirt starts after firewalld and layers its iptables/nft settings on top of what firewalld has done... without telling firewalld about its additions. When you restart firewalld, it clears all the firewall rules and rebuilds them according to what it knows. If you would first restart firewalld, and then restart libvirtd, you would get the same result as when booting on factory defaults.

Comment: I see, we should never restart firewalld, only use the `firewall-cmd --reload`. Thanks!